# Parsing a string to an array?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

I'm trying to get the average of up to 25 numbers. Right now, I'm confused on how to parse a `String` into an array. Here is the code as it stands:

```
final int SIZE = 25;
gradeArray = new double[SIZE];
String s;
int numElem = 0;
double average = 0;

do {
    s = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Grade", "");
    if (s == null || s == ("")) {

    } else {
        try {
            grades = Double.parseDouble(s);
            if (grades > SIZE) 

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your input must be numeric!",
                    "Bad             Data!", 0);
        }
    }
} while (s != null || !s.equals(""));
```

The `SIZE` constant is for testing purposes.

Comment: What problem are you running into? I see you have `Double.parseDouble (s)`, so you do have some knowledge is parsing. What's not working for you?

Comment: I don't see where you are attempting to add the string to the array. But in your case, you cannot; your array is an array of double values, which cannot be coerced into a double. What are you ultimately attempting to do? If you want to convert the string to a number for summing, you've already done that with the line `Double.paraeDouble(s);` line.

Comment: When I type that in, the compiler says I can't because it is a double[] not a double.

Comment: You may want to change your `while` condtion to `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: introduce some variable for counter and then do something like `gradeArray[counter++] = grades`... btw. your code is really of bad quality (`s == ("")`, `s != null || !s.equals("")`, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
{
 s = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Grade","");
    if(s != null && !(s.trim().equals(""))){
        gradeArray[i] = Double.parseDouble(s);
    }
    else{
        gradeArray[i] = 0;
    }

}

double sum=0;
for(int j=0;j<gradeArray.length;j++)
{
      sum+=gradeArray[j];
}


System.out.println("avaerage of grades ="+SIZE+" is ="+(sum/SIZE));
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to read up to 25 double constants as a single string and parse them into a double array.

```
final int SIZE = 25;
gradeArray = new double[SIZE];
String s;
int numElem = 0;
double average = 0;

do {
s = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Grade", "");
if (s == null || s == ("")) {

} else {
    try {
       // this will find double values in your string but ignores non double values
       Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?!=\\d\\.\\d\\.)([\\d.]+)").matcher(s);
       int temp = 0;
       while (m.find())
       {
         gradeArray[temp] = Double.parseDouble(m.group(1));
         temp ++;
         if(temp >= SIZE){
             break;
         }
       }

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your input must be numeric!",
                "Bad             Data!", 0);
    }
}
} while (s != null || !s.equals(""));
```